# What is the git ignore and remove from index options in Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, git

What is the different between Eclipse git ignore and remove from index? I use git eclipse plugin. I have few files that need to exclude.

Comment: Have you taken a look in the documentary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ignore" option will add the file to the [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file, which instructs Git to ignore all changes to the file (for example, Git will not add the file when you `add` the directory it is in).

Removing the file from the index effectively deletes it from the pending commit, without removing it from disk.  It is equivalent to [`git rm --cached`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) and is basically the exact opposite of `add`ing an untracked file.

Comment: ignore is OK. does index option only delete the files only from pending commit? what after that? if I try to commit it (file that remove from index)?

Comment: You can always re-add it again.  The end result is that the file is no longer tracked by Git, although it is of course still in the commit history.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the figure, if you click the ignore option for the corresponding file then it will generate ***.gitignore*** and includes repective file name in that. That means, it will not be in the Git stagging and ignores all changes for that perticular file.

[image]

To revert the file back then remove it from the ***.gitignore***

**goto Git Repositories--> .gitignore--->file name** and remove it

[image]